# How can I make this habit tracker interface more visually interesting?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, design-patterns, interface

I'm designing an interface for a habit tracker app where a user can view a list of their habits for the day and tap a button to mark a habit as complete.

I think the habit containers (meditate, journal, pray) look quite plain atm but I don't know how to make them stand out/look more visually interesting.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this screen less boring, specifically the habit containers?

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open because "lack of visual interest" can lead to poor adoption of habit-forming behaviors, which is a UX problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Add illustrations**

You could add a small illustration to each container, e.g. this image from undraw.co (free illustrations).
[image: woman meditating]

Maybe you could also make the circle showing the progress a little more rewarding. E.g. numbers get bigger or color intensifies when you are near completion.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- You can also use some imagery on your cards
- Add some gradients
- Add some texture
- Have more contrast between the cards and the background
- Comply with the accessibility standards (if you haven't already) between the text and the text background colours